# display certain elements in line

Tags: html, css

I am working on my personal website but I am having a little issue here. I am trying to create 4 skills which should be displayed `inline`, but whatever I try it just won't happen. I tried to apply `float:left` but this would cause the `skills` id to not have the overall content `CSS`, which I find very weird either. Here's the code:

```
<div id="skills">
  <div id="skill"> <img src="images/html.png" style="width:125px;height:125px;display:inline-block;">
    <p>Test1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="skill"> <img src="images/html.png" style="width:125px;height:125px;display:inline-block;">
    <p>Test2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="skill"> <img src="images/html.png" style="width:125px;height:125px;display:inline-block;">
    <p>Test3</p>
  </div>
  <div id="skill"> <img src="images/html.png" style="width:125px;height:125px;display:inline-block;">
    <p>Test4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I let these 4 "skills" display next to each other?

Kind regards

Answer (score 3):

First change **id** to **class** as `id` must be unique and there are 2 options to do this

1. float:left
2. display:inline-block

I prefer second one so that you don't need to clear after the floating div

```css
.skill{display:inline-block}
```

```html
<div id="skills">
  <div class="skill">
    <img src="images/html.png" style="width:125px;height:125px;display:inline-block;">
    <p>Test1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="skill">
    <img src="images/html.png" style="width:125px;height:125px;display:inline-block;">
    <p>Test2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="skill">
    <img src="images/html.png" style="width:125px;height:125px;display:inline-block;">
    <p>Test3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="skill">
    <img src="images/html.png" style="width:125px;height:125px;display:inline-block;">
    <p>Test4</p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem and Quick Fix**

The problem is that you need `display:inline-block` on the DIV elements, not on the IMG elements.

Example:

```
<div id="skill" style="display:inline-block;">
    <img src="images/html.png" style="width:125px;height:125px;;">
    <p>Test1</p>
</div>
```

---

**Suggestions**

1. Keep `id` attributes unique to the page. If you need duplicates, use the `class` attribute instead.
2. Don't use inline styles, add them to a CSS file instead and use the appropriate class name

Something like this:

```css
.skill {
  display: inline-block;
}

.skill img {
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
}
```

```html
<div id="skills">
  <div class="skill">
    <img src="images/html.png">
    <p>Test1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="skill">
    <img src="images/html.png">
    <p>Test2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="skill">
    <img src="images/html.png">
    <p>Test3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="skill">
    <img src="images/html.png">
    <p>Test4</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Do you know how i can put more space between the skills?

Comment: @Matthijs_210: You could try setting `margin-right` on the divs, for example: `margin-right: 50px;`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not be using ID's so instead replace these with "class". This is because ID's are unique. Another thing, do not define the style in each div, instead create a css file and put it there.

To solve your issue, you need to set the display of each "skill" div to inline-block. Here is a [Code Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zBQjQk) so you can see what I have done.

```css
#skills {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.skill {
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.skill img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="skills">
   <div class="skill">
      <img src="images/html.png">
      <p>Test1</p>
   </div>
   <div class="skill">
      <img src="images/html.png">
      <p>Test2</p>
   </div>
   <div class="skill">
      <img src="images/html.png">
      <p>Test3</p>
   </div>
   <div class="skill">
      <img src="images/html.png" >
      <p>Test4</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- First of all remove tag id="skill" because it must be unique (You can't use same id more than once in one page).
- Remove "display:inline-block;" from image style and add in parent div of each image **style="float:left"**.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this css for positioning your elements inline**

```
#skills > div {
  float: left;
    }

#skills img{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 125px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 125px;
}

#skills p {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```